# DolphinDB Exception: System handle is not able to serialize

Tags: database, rpc, dolphindb

I have deployed a DolphinDB cluster successfully like this:

File `cluster.nodes`:

```
localSite,mode
192.168.1.112:1210:agent1,agent
192.168.1.112:1221:DFS_NODE1121,datanode
192.168.1.112:1222:DFS_NODE1122,datanode
192.168.1.112:1223:DFS_NODE1123,datanode
192.168.1.112:1224:DFS_NODE1124,datanode
192.168.1.112:1225:DFS_NODE1125,datanode

192.168.1.120:1210:agent2,agent
192.168.1.120:1221:DFS_NODE1201,datanode
192.168.1.120:1222:DFS_NODE1202,datanode
192.168.1.120:1223:DFS_NODE1203,datanode
192.168.1.120:1224:DFS_NODE1204,datanode
192.168.1.120:1225:DFS_NODE1205,datanode
```

Then I connected to server `192.168.1.112:1221` and tried to call function `rpc` in this way:

```
dbDir = 'dfs://valueDB'
schema = table(100000000:0, ["devId", "temperature"], ["INT", "DOUBLE"] )
if(existsDatabase(dbDir))
   dropDatabase(dbDir)
db = database(dbDir, VALUE, 0..99) 
dev = db.createPartitionedTable(schema,`dev,`devId)
dev.append!(table(1..10 as devId, 20.5+rand(10,10) as temperature))

rpc("DFS_NODE1122", loadTable, db, `dev)
```

But the system threw the exception message like this:

```
Execution was completed with exception
System handle is not able to serialize.
```

So, how to call `rpc` correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Like a file handle or a socket handle, a database handle is valid on the node where it was opened. For this reason, DolphinDB disables serializing a database handle to a remote data node.

loadTable accepts a database directory as well. Please modify your code as follows:

```
rpc("DFS_NODE1122", loadTable, dbDir, `dev)
```

But the above code doesn't make any sense. Since the table `dev is a distributed table, you can load it on any data node.